# Keep getting error #1064 when I try to create a trigger in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a trigger to import a field from another table when a new row is inserted but get the error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 6
```

I'm using the sql tab in phpmyadmin to enter the code.

I've read all the related questions on here, perused several other sites with articles on mysql triggers but can't find anything that helps.

- I've tried with // at the end of the line prior to END//
- I've tried with ; at the end of the line prior to END//

Nothing seems to work.

My trigger code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER towns2_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON towns2 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.regionid = (Select RegionID from world_map
where (world_map.X = new.mapx) AND (world_map.Y = new.mapy))
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Both towns2 and world_map tables exist and have the required columns.

As far as I can tell this should fetch the RegionID field from any row in the world_map table that has X & Y fields matching the new mapx and mapy columns but all I can get is this error.

No doubt I've got a really simple error in this somewhere but for the life of me I can't find it and all help is greatfully recieved.

**UPDATE**
Re-created the code as shown by @Chris J below in the myphpadmin trigger form, ignored the big red X against the END statement and hit the GO button - it worked so I guess the problem was not with my code but with my chosen method of creating the trigger. The code as created by phpmyadmin is shown below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `towns2_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `towns2`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET NEW.regionid =
(Select RegionID from world_map
where (X = new.mapx) AND (Y = new.mapy));
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you've mentioned it already, the following works perfectly for me:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER towns2_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON towns2 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.regionid = (Select RegionID from world_map
where (world_map.X = new.mapx) AND (world_map.Y = new.mapy));
END//
```

This is based on a guess of your schema from your query.  The trigger now exists and is visible in Heidi as follows:

[image]

Comment: Just typed the code exactly as your screenshot into the trigger form in phpmyadmin. I got a red X against the line with END indicating an error but proceeded anyway and it worked :)  Thanks @Chris J

Comment: Might be worth using something like HeidiSQL if you're able to - phpmyadmin can be troublesome when giving false negatives with more intricate queries

Comment: Thanks @Chris J - I'll be having a look into that later tonight/tomorrow.